# Tapping on native Android notification does not open application

Tags: bug, notifications, android-app

In version 0.1.50 when I tap on the native Android notification that the Stack Exchange app generates, nothing happens. The notification dismisses but the app does not open and the notifications are not marked as read inside the app.

Comment: And now everything seems to be working. I do know I had multiple question notifications, so could that be the cause?

Comment: Maybe mark it for closing then?